# Espresso Web - How to click an element in an unnamed web view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview, android-espresso, android-espresso-web

I have a web view which loads another web view with in. The structure follows as below:

- Web view (name_1)

  - View
  - View
  - Web view (No Name)

Going through the UI test I end up needing to click an element in the inner web view after it gets created. As it doesn't have a name, how am I able to access that web view to click the element?

Usually I would do the below using the named web view as an example

```
 onWebView(R.id.name_1)
            .withNoTimeout()
            .withElement(findElement(...))
            .perform(webClick())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use `allOf` and `isDescendantOfA` to get the child WebView.

Try this:

```
onWebView(allOf(
        withClassName(containsString(WebView.class.getSimpleName())),
        isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.name_1)))
).withNoTimeout().withElement(findElement(...)).perform(webClick());
```

Comment: where does onWebView come from?

Comment: @JPM https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/web#implementing-webview - "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web"